# Java Internal Frame resize event listener?

Tags: java, jinternalframe

I can not find any information on how to catch the "`resize`" event of a `JInternalFrame`, I really mean *internal* frame.

Indeed, the `InternalFrameListener` does not catch the "`resize`" events.

Should I write it myself using the "`JInternalFrame.addComponentListener(...)`" ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `addComponentListener()` to add a resize listener to the `JInternalFrame`.

The most compact way to do this would be to use a `ComponentAdapter` and only override the `componentResized(final ComponentEvent e)` method:

```
jInternalFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent e) {
        super.componentResized(e);
        System.out.println("Resizing");
    }
});
```

Take a look at this simple, complete example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Example::createFrame);
    }

    private static void createFrame() {

        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JDesktopPane jDesktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        jDesktopPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));

        JInternalFrame jInternalFrame = new JInternalFrame();
        jInternalFrame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        jInternalFrame.setResizable(true);
        jInternalFrame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        jInternalFrame.setLocation(100, 100);
        jInternalFrame.setVisible(true);

        jInternalFrame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(final ComponentEvent e) {
                super.componentResized(e);
                System.out.println("Resizing");
            }
        });

        jDesktopPane.add(jInternalFrame);

        jFrame.setContentPane(jDesktopPane);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. But now I run into another problem since my class already extends another one which extends jInternalFrame.

Comment: @Titi why is that a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your hepl. You are right... no problem. First, I thought I had to extend ComponentAdapter (which I can not since my class already extends jInternalFrame. I also found that I can implement ComponentListener, which is another way of doing it.